# What's wrong with my Meteor publication?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

I have a publication, essentially what's below:

```
Meteor.publish('entity-filings', function publishFunction(cik, queryArray, limit) {

  if (!cik || !filingsArray)
    console.error('PUBLICATION PROBLEM');

  var limit = 40;


  var entityFilingsSelector = {};
  if (filingsArray.indexOf('all-entity-filings') > -1)
    entityFilingsSelector = {ct: 'filing',cik: cik};
  else
    entityFilingsSelector = {ct:'filing', cik: cik, formNumber: { $in: filingsArray} };


  return SB.Content.find(entityFilingsSelector, {
    limit: limit
  });


});
```

I'm having trouble with the `filingsArray` part.  `filingsArray` is an array of regexes for the Mongo $in query.  I can hardcode `filingsArray` in the publication as `[/8-K/]`, and that returns the correct results.  But I can't get the query to work properly when I pass the array from the router.  See the debugged contents of the array in the image below.  The second and third images are the client/server debug contents indicating same content on both client and server, and also identical to when I hardcode the array in the query.

**My question is: what am I missing?  Why won't my query work, or what are some likely reasons it isn't working?**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that first screenshot, that's a string that looks like a regex literal, not an actual `RegExp` object. So `{$in: ["/8-K/"]}` will only match literally `"/8-K/"`, which is not the same as `{$in: [/8-K/]}`.

Regexes are not EJSON-able objects, so you won't be able to send them over the wire as publish function arguments or method arguments or method return values. I'd recommend sending a string, then inside the publish function, use `new RegExp(...)` to construct a regex object.

If you're comfortable adding new methods on the `RegExp` prototype, you could try making `RegExp` an EJSON-able type, by putting this in your server and client code:

```
RegExp.prototype.toJSONValue = function () {
  return this.source;
};

RegExp.prototype.typeName = function () {
  return "regex";
}

EJSON.addType("regex", function (str) {
  return new RegExp(str);
});
```

After doing this, you should be able to use regexes as publish function arguments, method arguments and method return values. See this [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/mSYa7jHiHChfh2Mjf/Regex%20EJSON).

Answer (score 1):

`/8-K/`.. that's a weird regex. Try `/8\-K/`.

A minus (-) sign is a range indicator and usually used inside square brackets. The reason why it's weird because how could you even calculate a range between 8 and K? If you do not escape that, it *probably* wouldn't be used to match anything (thus your query would not work). Sometimes, it does work though. Better safe than never.

`/8\-K/` matches the string `"8-K"` anywhere once.. which I assume you are trying to do.

Also it would help if you would ensure your publication would always return something.. here's a good area where you could fail:

```
if (!cik || !filingsArray)
    console.error('PUBLICATION PROBLEM');
```

If those parameters aren't filled, `console.log` is probably not the best way to handle it. A better way:

```
if (!cik || !filingsArray) {
     throw "entity-filings: Publication problem.";
     return false; 
} else {
  // .. the rest of your publication
}
```

This makes sure that the client does not wait unnecessarily long for publications statuses as you have successfully ensured that in any (input) case you returned either `false` or a `Cursor` and nothing in between (like surprise `undefined`s, unfilled Cursors, other garbage data.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: I had actually tried that.  The thing is that the `8-K` example is just the simplest one of multiple things that I'm trying to select.  But yeah, I tried that. Thanks for that extra input about the error stuff

Comment: have you tried `console.log`-ing on what `entityFilingsSelector` would output before the `.find`?